# How to display customized popup message box on the server in asp.net page using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have an ASP.NET page that updates customer profile information.
After updating and when the user clicks on Update button, i want to display alert message.

1. Can we customize it to edit the MsgBox title?
2. Can we edit the default msg that is displaying? If yes, Can anybody provide any samples.

I earlier used customized popup from AjaxToolkit. I have issues with that in IE6.0. So I don't want to go for that.

Comment: You can't link images from your C drive on the internet...

Comment: you really need to upload that image somewhere for this to make sense!

Comment: After the customer updates their profile and clicks update you want to throw an alert? What is it supposed to say?"you have successfully update your profile"?  Then what happens? Why not just redirect them back to the not editable version of their profile?

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the popup provided by the AJAX toolkit personally. I much prefer one of the jQuery plugins. You're likely to find these to be much simpler to set up and if you do run into trouble you're likely to find a lot more resources on the particular issue you're having.

Comment: ...and it might be a better user experience to use a growl rather than a popup.

Comment: I agree, I really like the jquery dialog, the link is http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ for demo and more information